# In grails, my HTTPBuilder call the one rest URL that return a gsp page.How to display the gsp page?

Tags: grails, groovy, httpbuilder

I have two grails applications are application1 and application2. application1 use HTTPBuilder to call the application2 that return one template(gsp page). How can i display gsp page(the response) in my application1.I got status code 200. after that what i will do to display the page?how to return that response?

```
static def users(String akey,String userName){
        try {
           def ret = null
           def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://192.168.1.7:8080/Play0.1/main/userGroup")
           http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.HTML) {
               uri.query = [ aKey:aKey, userName:userName]
               headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'
               response.success = { resp,html -> println resp.status


                 }
               response.failure = { resp -> println "Unexpected error: ${resp.status} : ${resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase}" }
           }
           return ret
       } catch (groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace()
           return null
       } catch (java.net.ConnectException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace()
           return null
       }
   }
```

That users action returns one gsp page.

Comment: what you mean with 'I got status code 302'?

Comment: that my response's status

Comment: So, you need to respond with `html`, right?

Comment: ya.now i got 200 as my response.

Answer (score 0):

As said in Wikipedia :

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
```

You should follow the `Location` header to obtain the content.

You may check that your `application2` redirect or not and consider to implement REST design in `application2` to avoid redirect in web service.